# Creating analytics events on a Chrome extension on content received from an external domain

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-analytics

I have a Chrome extension and attached Google analytics on it successfully.
Now I want to track events.
The thing is, the entire view of the extension is brought in via ajax from an external domain, not sure if this is the problem or not but i'm not able to create events.
Here is what I have:

on content.js I have the analytics code which runs just fine. and below the event attempts:

```
   var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxx-x']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
  ga.src = 'https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();



$('.gotodiv').click(function(){
    var url = $(this).find('a').attr('href');

    ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', url);

  });
```

Again, the "gotodiv" isn't on my popup.html it's what is brought in from another domain. Is it even possible to create an event this way?

Comment: The variabel `ga` is define in an anonymous function, so it can be use only in it. I don't know the rest of your code so I don't know if it's define later. But in the given code, it should be the source of the problem.

Comment: And a question, where this code is executed ? In chrome extension there is 3 major place a code can be run : in background, in popup of browser/page action, in a content script. The behavior of the code should not be the same depend of where it executed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. First, ga is defined by analytics at the top of the file as you can see. the event i wrote is used on another site and works perfectly. The script runs in the background. I'm starting to think that because the action happens on a results page that is pulled in from a different place, maybe i don't have access to it.
Does that make any sense?

Comment: You have to know that Chrome is sandboxing a great part of the code you'r running so it have no access to javascript of page you are injecting. I don't know if it's helping you

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought. I tried to manipulate the css with JQ with no luck either so i guess i'll have to live with it with no events...
Thanks for your help

Comment: But for events, if they are DOM events, You should have access to it.

Comment: I wasn't able to create a DOM event either

Comment: You can by pass sandbox limitation by injecting a `<script>` tag in the DOM. The script in this tag will be executed on the page javascript vm. It's a litle dirty but you can use it to transform you'r event into a DOM event accessible by content scripts